# GestureDetector that overrides children GestureDetectors?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to make a GestureDetector override the functionality of all children GestureDetectors?

I have a complex Widget that I would like to be able to easily override all of its behavior at a high level. For example, locking a free user out of functionality.

Comment: That's the default behavior of gesture detector (as long as you specify a gesture callback)

Comment: I don't believe that is correct.

Comment: Sorry my bad, the default value is `deferToChild`. I'll post an answer

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is, I have tried all the different HitTestBehaviors and none of them override my children GestureDetectors. :)

Comment: What do you mean by override ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To temporarily disable all child gesture detectors, use an `IgnorePointer` widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool ignoreChildGestures = true;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('parent tapped');
      },
      child: IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: ignoreChildGestures,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (details) {
            // won't be called when ignoring is set to true
            print('child tap down!');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It works but the top level GestureBehavior must have its behavior property set to opaque

Comment: `AbsorbPointer` seems to work better - no need to set `behavior` to `opaque`

Comment: Both `AbsorbPointer` and `IgnorePointer` work for me. But I use `Inkwell` instead of `GestureDetector`

Answer (score 7):

You can change `HitTestBehavior behavior` of `GestureDetector` to `HitTestBehavior.opaque`

```
GestureDetector(
   behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
   ...
)
```

By default, it uses `HitTestBehavior.deferToChild`.

Comment: That is not overriding my children, unfortunately.

Comment: Worked for me if I added an IgnorePointer as a child, then added my Widget as that child.
GestureDetector -> IgnorePointer -> MyChild

Answer (score -2):

Another method: create an onTap attribute then pass that in to the child widget:

```
// Somewhere in parent widget
ChildWidget(onTap: () => doSomething())

class ChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  ChildWidget({Key key, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  final Function onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        onTap();
      },
      child: SomeWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

You'd probably want to make onTap optional, and if onTap is null, don't wrap in a GestureDetector.